# Authenticate to apple.com from Android using Security key

Tags: android, fido

Android FIDO2 SDK requires uploading "assetlinks.json" to relying party server to authenticate using the external security keys. To authenticate to apple.com from an Android app using a security key need to upload "assetlinks.json" to the Apple server. is there any way or documentation to upload "assetlinks.json" in the Apple server to support Android FIDO2 SDK?

I could not find any documentation regarding this.